# How do I test React-Responsive components with Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am using the library React-Reponsive.
https://github.com/contra/react-responsive

I am struggling to figure out how to test components that are nested in React-Responsive Media Query Components:

```
export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={750}>
         <Header />
      </MediaQuery>
    );
  }
}
```

-

```
describe("AppContainer", () => {
  let App;
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><AppContainer location={location} /></Provider>);
    App = wrapper.find(AppContainer);

  });
  it('to have a <Header /> component', () => { 
    console.log(App.debug());
    expect(App.find(Header)).to.have.length(1);
  });
}
```

The test result:

```
1) AppContainer to have a <Header /> component:
AssertionError: expected { Object (component, root, ...) } to have a length of 1 but got 0
```

The relevant part of the output of the console.log is:

```
<MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={750} values={{...}} />
```

Indicating that Header is indeed not appearing in the render tree. However if I remove the MediaQuery and make Header a direct child of AppContainer the test passes.

I imagine this is not a bug as I'm very new to Enzyme and testing components in general. Any help or examples would be appreciated.

Please note: The other tests I have on this component are passing fine. I am confident that the imports and setup are all correct.

Comment: Should it not be `expect(App.find(MediaQuery)).to.have.length(1);`

Comment: Yeah that would work for testing for Media Query, what I'm looking for though is how to test for Header in this case

Answer (score 5):

Issue was that Media Query is looking for window.matchMedia which with jsdom is undefined.

In this case I needed to use the Server Side Rendering implementation. However this would require a static value for width, which breaks the responsiveness.

My solution is to set a global variable on the test virtual DOM.

```
window.testMediaQueryValues = {width:740};
```

Then MediaQuery can access them if they are there:

```
<MediaQuery maxWidth={smallViewMaxWidth} values={window.testMediaQueryValues}>
```

In the case when the variable is not set, the null values are ignored and the Component renders as usual.

Big thanks to @Contra for his help and super library

Comment: Maybe react-responsive was different when you wrote that, but as of today, `values` is not used in a browser context. So you don't need the global test value. Instead, you can pass a prop that serves the save purpose.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira can you elaborate on that? not sure what you mean about the passing a prop to serve the same purpose

Comment: I think what I mean was that your component can take in an optional prop such as `width` or `displayMode` that it can use to decide which sub-component to render, instead of relying on the window state to tell you the viewport width.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was adding a mocked `react-responsive` component using a `__mocks__` directory. Basically create the following file in the directory structure:

-`your-component`

--`component-using-media-query.js`

--`__mocks__`

---`react-responsive.js`

Then you can mock out the `MediaQuery` component in the `react-responsive.js` file.

```
const MediaQuery = ({ children }) => children;

export default MediaQuery;
```

Comment: After hours of trying solutions, this worked and is so simple.

Comment: This works... But how to add different widths?.. Right now it renders all the <MediaQuery> as per the mock..

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work using `react-responsive` v7.0.0.

Given:

```
<MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={750}>
  <Header />
</MediaQuery>
```

The following works:

```
import { Context as ResponsiveContext } from 'react-responsive'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

const wrappingComponent = ResponsiveContext.Provider
const wrappingComponentProps = { value: { width: 750 } }
const mountProps = { wrappingComponent, wrappingComponentProps }

const wrapper = mount(<AppContainer />, mountProps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking the *react-responsive* dependency in your unit test. Working with Webpack, I'm using [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader) for injecting test dependencies to modules. You can import your component using "inject-loader" and pass it which dependencies you want to overwrite.

Example:

```
import YourComponentInjector from 'inject-loader!../YourComponent.jsx';
```

and then

```
class MediaQueryDesktopMock extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const {minDeviceWidth, children} = this.props;
      if(minDeviceWidth === 765) {
        return (<div>{children}</div>)
      }
      return <span/>;
    }
  }
  let YourComponentMock = YourComponentInjector({
    'react-responsive': MediaQueryDesktopMock
  });
```

you can then test for specific media queries